# No Solution Set for augmented coefficient matrix $[A\mid b]$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let there be $Ax=b$ a set of m equations with n unknowns.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A) \neq \operatorname{rank}[A|b] $ the system of equations does not have a solution

Does it mean that: there is a pivot number in b $\iff$ there is no solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means that the row-reduced matrix of $A$ has at least one row of all zeros, for which the corresponding row in coefficient matrix $[A\mid b]$ does not: i.e., after row-reduction of $[A\mid b]$, there exists at least one row with all zeros except for a non-zero entry in the right-most column ($b$).

Such a system of equations is *inconsistent* and so no solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More precisely, if you encode $A x = b$ as an adjoined matrix $[A|b]$ and row-reduce, there is a solution iff the last nonzero row is not $[0 \dots 0 | 1]$, that is, if there is no pivot of $[A|b]$ in the last column. This is easy to see: If the last row is not $[0 \dots 0 | 1]$ there are nonzero entries left of the last column, so that the last row, and hence the whole system, admits a solution. If that is the last row, the original system is equivalent to one that contains the equation $0 = 1$, and so it has no solution.